# How to get elements that have no ID in VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am trying to write a script to drive my IExplorer. It works okay up to a point but then I need to enter a value in a `textarea` and click a button while they both have no ID. I have no idea how I can move arround in the HTML DOM using VBScript but it was suggested somewhere to use `document.all` somehow. I was also thinking of maybe using a JS script to give them IDs and then go back and use `document.getElementbyid` but I don't know how to run a JS script from within the VBScript with the initialised document object in mind. What I have so far is:

```
Option Explicit
With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  .Visible = True
  .Navigate "https://adwords.google.co.uk/um/Logout"
  Do While .Busy
WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
  .Document.getElementByID("Email").Value = "testtestingtton@gmail.com"
  .Document.getElementByID("Passwd").Value = "PWD"
  'Note: You could just get the form and submit it, but
  'you'll miss out on any special JavaScript associated 
  'with the Submit button.
  .Document.getElementByID("signIn").Click
  Do While .Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
      .Navigate "https://adwords.google.co.uk/o/Targeting/Explorer?"
        Do While .Busy
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
'here begins the problem'
  .Document.All.tags("sB5 sPEB").Value = "southpark"
  '.Document.getElementsByTagName("sJ1").Click'

End With
```

Also since the field I am trying to fill is

```
<textarea style="overflow-y: hidden; height: 36px;" class="sB5 sPEB"></textarea>
```

and it has no value attribute how is its value inputed?

Comment: You may be using IE 8 or previous version. getElementsByClassName() not supported by IE DOM. Please Check This quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [MSXML DOM methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757828) such as `hasChildNodes` and `nextNode` to move around, or `selectSingleNode` and `selectNodes` for direct access. The text value is stored as a child of the `textarea` element in a [text node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).

**References**

- [How to Create a Dynamic Email Signature](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/How-To-Create-A-Dynamic-Email-Signature)
- [How to automate the deletion of backups in SharePoint Server 2007 and in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 by using a Visual Basic script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941330)
- [Use XPath to Perform a Case-Insensitive Search with MSXML](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315719)
- [How To Use XPath Queries in MSXML DOM selectNodes Method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288913)
- [Using the right version of MSXML in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `.Document.All.tags("sB5 sPEB").Value = "southpark"`

Try below codes

1. check if the class is unique

   ```
   .Document.getElementsByClassName("sB5 sPEB").Value = "southpark"
   ```

Otherwise use a for loop and with if statement send value